# Sliding a element from right to left on scroll using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have li elements that are side by side. One of the li elements appears when I scroll down to the bottom and disappears when I scroll back up. I have achieved this with jQuery using fadeIn and fadeOut. However, I am trying to achieve this using a sliding effect rather than a fading effect.

Below is the code:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
   var y = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (y > 180) {
     $('.header-avail')
     .attr('style', 'display: block !important;')
     .fadeIn();
   } 
   else {
     $('.header-avail').fadeOut();
   }   
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="primary-menu" class="menu nav-menu" aria-expanded="false">

 <li id="menu-item-386" class="header-avail menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-386">
  <a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after"><span class="menu-image-title">Contact Us</span></a>
 </li>

 <li id="menu-item-504" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-504" style="display: inline-block !important;">
  <a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after"><span class="menu-image-title">Check Availability</span></a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

[Fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/1a01xtxL/1/)

Comment: Do you want Sliding effect....?

Comment: yes sliding effect

Comment: Do you want Like this [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1a01xtxL/2/)

Comment: @MaulikBhatt no i want it to slide from right to left

Comment: Then just animate the css 'margin-left' property you will get which you want.

Comment: how would i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hiding the `li` concerned, give it a zero width, and animate that. For that to work, you also need to set the margin to zero (so the other visible `li` sticks to the right side of the window), and give the animating `li` an `overflow: hidden` attribute:

```js
$(document).scroll(function () {
  var show = $(this).scrollTop() > 180,
      visible = $('.header-avail').width() > 0;
  if (show === visible) return; // nothing to do
  $('.header-avail').stop().animate({marginLeft: 20 * show, width: 100 * show});
});
```

```css
body {height: 2000px;}

#primary-menu {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0; /* all margins 0 */
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 250px;
}
#primary-menu > li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0; 
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    height: 300px;
    float: right;
}
/* show, but with zero width and margin */
.header-avail{width: 0; margin: 0; overflow: hidden}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="primary-menu" class="menu nav-menu" aria-expanded="false">
   <li id="menu-item-386" class="header-avail menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-386"><a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after"><span class="menu-image-title">Contact Us</span></a></li>
   <li id="menu-item-504" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-504" style="display: inline-block !important;"><a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after"><span class="menu-image-title">Check Availability</span></a></li>
</ul>
```